# Lambdaで複数のCloudWatchルールを有効化したい

Tags: javascript, aws, aws-lambda, aws-cloudwatch

AWSのLambdaで、AWS.CloudWatchEventsクラスのenableRuleを使って複数のCloudWatchルールを有効にしたいのですが、Handlerに渡すイベントの書き方がわかりません。以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
以下のenableRuleのリファレンス通りにやった場合の1件だけのステータスの切り替えはうまくいきました。
(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#enableRule-property)

まったく知見がないもので、JSONの渡し方が悪かったりparamsの書き方が違ったりするのかもしれませんがご教授いただければ幸いです。

```
InvalidParameterType: Expected params.Name to be a string
```

Lambdaに渡すJSONの例:

```
{
  "Name": [
    "test-sample-activate",
    "test-sample-activate2",
    "test-sample-activate3"
  ]
}
```

index.jsの例:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cw = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents();

exports.handler = event => {

    for (let i = 0; i < event.Name.length; i++) {
        cw.enableRule({ Name: [event.Name[i]}] }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

---

修正したコード:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var cw = new AWS.CloudWatchEvents();

exports.handler = event => {

    for (let i = 0; i < event.Name.length; i++) {
        cw.enableRule({ Name: event.Name[i] }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

自分が参考にしていた別のメソッドのリファレンスの書き方を真似してしまっていました…
しっかり自分で考えてプログラミングしたいと思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> cw.enableRule({ Name: [event.Name[i]}] }, function(err, data) {
> ```

ここは

```
cw.enableRule({ Name: event.Name[i] }, function(err, data) {
```

ですか？

Comment: あっ… Name[i]のあとの}は、元のソースから削ったため誤って付いてしまっていたものですが、event.Name[i]を囲っている[]は開発者ガイドにそういった例があったため見落としていました…

しょぼい間違いでしたが教えて下さりありがとうございます！正常に動作いたしました。